# Akonadi and Kmail using 100% CPU

Tags: kde, kmail, akonadi

I've been using KMail for a month or two now and have so far had no problems with it. However, today my laptop died after the battery ran out of power, and since then whenever I log in I see a steady 100% CPU use from the following processes:

- akonadi_mailfilter_agent
- akonadi_imap_resource
- akonadi_nepomuk_feeder

Running `akonadictl stop` kills the processes and returns CPU usage to reasonable levels, but then KMail complains that it cannot run without akonadi. Can I clear some type of cache or other settings to get KMail back on its feet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is a bit painful, but I at least got everything back up and running again. Here's what I had to do:

1. Run `akonadictl stop` to stop akonadi
2. Remove everything under `~/.local/share/akonadi`
3. Remove everything under `~/.config/akonadi`
4. Restart akonadi

After restarting akonadi, it took a good 15 minutes to resync everything. However, the CPU usage during the sync was about 40% per daemon, much better than 100%.

Comment: I've been searching for a fix for a LONG time and this actually seems to have done the trick. Thanks Nik!

Comment: Well, looks my post on what happens if you do the above is gonna be deleted, so I will just says this: It might work without trouble. But if you use KMail, performing the deletion as described will mess up the KMail confguration, at least the IMAP part. Acceptable if the config is short, not so much if you have 10 IMAP accounts...

Comment: Update: DO NOT DO THIS. It turns out even the groups in kaddressbook are messed up and either cannot be opened or contain addresses randomly picked from kaddressbook. (probably because they use numeric identifiers into the database that you destroy by following the above)